# Case insensitive MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Release>Setup.exe /QUI
ET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=SQL2008 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=sa /SA
PWD=xxx /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 Setup 10.00.2731.00
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following error occurred:
The state of your SQL Server installation was not changed after the setup execut
ion. Please review the summary.txt logs for further details.

Error result: -2068643838
Result facility code: 1203
Result error code: 2

Please review the summary.txt log for further details
```

username, passwd and insatnce are coreect. I try with this manual:

http://v-reality.info/2010/10/vcenter-server-and-microsoft-sql-server-collation-conflicts/

log:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643838
  Exit facility code:            1203
  Exit error code:               2
  Exit message:                  The state of your SQL Server installation was not changed after the setup execution. Please review the summary.txt logs for further details.
  Start time:                    2011-03-28 20:15:39
  End time:                      2011-03-28 20:16:11
  Requested action:              RebuildDatabase

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  MITJAB-NOTEBOK
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows Vista
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     Slovenija
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Integration Services                     1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008
  SQLProductFamilyCode:          {628F8F38-600E-493D-9946-F4178F20A8A9}
  ProductName:                   SQL2008
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation edition:          EVAL

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        RebuildDatabase
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  HELP:                          False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQL2008
  QUIET:                         True
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           sa
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20110328_201509\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20110328_201509\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.NoopWorkflowException
    Message: 
        The state of your SQL Server installation was not changed after the setup execution. Please review the summary.txt logs for further details
```

.

Comment: Looks like you are hitting the same issue as the poster here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/738f5c3e-733c-4560-bbd3-22b78ead03aa

Comment: this was not demo version, it is production vesrion. sql 2008 standard edition

Comment: It says " Installation edition: EVAL" in the log file.

Comment: Was it installed as "eval" then you upgraded? If not maybe one of the other suggestions in that thread apply (are you on 64 bit running x86>)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Sql Server 2008 R2, try running the setup.exe from :

> \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
>   Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2

You can tell there might be an issue/mismatch if the version in the command line isn't matched with the version of the running sql server -- for example the Management Studio says it's version 10.50.1600 whereas running the wrong **setup.exe** shows a version of 10.00.2731.00 .

Answer (score 1):

I wasted so much time on this today trying normal Command Prompts, elevated Command Prompts, the setup.exe on the SQL Server CD, the setup.exe in the Bootstrap folder, and so on. In the end it turned out to be a simple answer: the /InstanceName parameter is really just the instance name.

i.e.: if when using SSMS you connect to DevServer\DevInstance,2433 then the parameter is just /InstanceName=DevInstance

I have tested this from both the CD version of setup.exe (Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 Setup 10.00.1600.22) and the setup.exe in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Release (Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 Setup 10.00.5500.00).

My full command line from either place was:

```
setup.exe /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=DevInstance /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /SAPWD="..." /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
```